# How do I convert this curl command to Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, curl, nsmutableurlrequest

the command:

```
curl -X POST -F "search={\"page\":\"1\",\"county\":\"18\",\"type\":\"J\"} " -H "Host: 118932.ro" http://118932.ro/dezv/ipa/index.php
```

This is what I have so far:

```
url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.118932.ro/dezv/ipa/index.php"];

NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:self.requestData options:0 error:&error];
NSString *bodyString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *dataString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"search=%@\"",bodyString];
NSData *dataBody = [dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:dataBody];
[request setValue:@"118932.ro" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Host"];
```

where self.requestData is the following dictionary

```
self.requestData = @{@"page" : @"1", @"county" : @"18", @"type" : @"J"};
```

but this doesnt seem to give me any results after I do this

```
self.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

[self.connection start];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code I use. The -F parameter in cUrl specifies the actual post data, so you may want to use the string `"search={\"page\":\"1\",\"county\":\"18\",\"type\":\"J\"} "` as is. You should call this code in a background thread as the synchronous call will block the UI.

```
/**
 *  Do an HTTP POST request and return the results
 *
 *  @param  NSString *  url     the URL
 *  @param  NSString *  post    the POST data
 *
 *  @return NSDictionary *      a dictionary containing the response, error, and data
 */
+ (NSDictionary *)httpPostRequestWithUrl:(NSString *)url post:(NSString *)post
{
    NSData *postData     = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)[postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:30]; // set timeout for 30 seconds

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    NSHTTPURLResponse   *response = nil;
    NSError         *error = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    NSMutableDictionary *rc = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    if ( response )
        [rc setObject:response forKey:@"response"];
    if ( error )
        [rc setObject:error forKey:@"error"];
    if ( data )
        [rc setObject:data forKey:@"data"];

    return (NSDictionary *)rc;
}
```

Comment: well I would like the UI to be stopped when the request is not yet completed, so is it really necessary that I run this code in the background?

Comment: Not necessary at all. Just an FYI. I do the same thing actually.

Comment: ok thanks larry, I am gonna implement the above code and select it as an answer, once I test it out :D

Comment: is it required that I send the postLength also?

Comment: I don't believe so, but it is a habit of mine.

Comment: my curl returns results, but my objective-C request isn't returning any results, I am just not sure whats going on